# How can I disable the grey highlightening on askubuntu?

Tags: support, tags

I don't like the grey highlightening on askubuntu, it highlights every two questions, and is just very annoying.

How can I disable it?

since I don't really know why it's being highlighted, makes it also much harder to stop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do so is to add a tag that you're either interested in, or that gets very little useage (like [vpcy](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/vpcy) which has only one question attached to it on the main site). This would be a stop gap until the StackExchange team produces configuration options for default highlighting

Comment: this is just an idea, but maybe someone could create a tag, with the only purpose to not have any questions linked to it. it could work. And then by some magic close the tag form being used! :)

Comment: I'm sure with some time and feedback the SE team will implement changes. They're always on the path of innovation trying to make the SE network more user friendly. :)

Comment: I would love to have a preferences page. if you want new functions to appear or just have the same "original" that would be more user friendly. a bit like using LTS or using the newer versions. :)

Comment: There is a tag called 'x' that has never been used before.

Comment: cool, or u just create a tag called "non-grey" :)

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/non-grey

Answer (score 0):

Override the style sheet (a good browser should let you add site specific user style sheets):

```
.tagged-interesting {
    background-color: #f7f7f7 !important;
}
```